# how to bottom align an image to a h1?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I am trying to bottom align an image to a h1 text, but I am not achieving the desired results.
I tried adding two divs and align them that did not work well, now I am trying to align a span but I am not getting the desired result as well.

```
<div id="formheader">
        <div id="formlogo"> <img src="../../Pictures/EditIcon.gif" width="17" height="20" alt="login logo"> </div>
        <div id="formtitle"> <span> <img src="../../Pictures/EditIcon.gif" width="17" height="20" alt="login logo">Editor</span> </div>
      </div>
```

[image: aligning issue]

Any tips on how to align images with text? I had to change from h1 to span because it would not align as h1.

Comment: img{ vertical-align:center;} may be add float:left;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write like this:

```
img{
 vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: @AdamSweeney check your code you put span inside IMG tag. Which is wrong

Comment: guess there may be a problem with my image, because it doesn't look like it align even with vertical-align: bottom